# ES file explorer, how can I get the complete folder path?

Tags: file-system, file-management

Sometimes ES file explorer will open directly into a folder, for example if I download a file, it will ask if I *want to open the files containing folder*.
I select yes and then get something like this:

[image]

Unfortunately this doesnt help me if I need to locate the file using another application.
I tried the dropdown (the little blue triangle below "adobe acrobat" in the picture), but this only gives the *history* of previously visited folder paths.
How can I get a full path of the current directory in ES explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current directory is the first entry in the history. i checked just now. its just below the sd card list.

Comment: thanks, I found there are times that the current directory doesnt show in the history. and Ive even tried refreshing the screen. So I dont really trust this method, but its probably the best solution I'm going to get!